# Select Case not returning expected value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I believe I'm using the CASE statement correctly, but it's not returning the expected values.

```
Option Explicit   
Option Compare Text

Sub airport()
    Dim y As Long
    Dim airportname As String

    Select Case airportname
    Case "Los Angeles Airport"
        y = 1
    Case "Long Beach Airport"
        y = 2
    Case "Ontario Airport"
        y = 3
    Case "Palm Springs Airport"
        y = 4
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("Something's Wrong")
    End Select

    airportname = WS.Range("A2").Value 
    Range("B1").Value = y
    Range("C1").Value = 2                        'expected value of B1
    Range("D1").Value = WS.Range("A2").Value     'expected value is Long Beach Airport
    airportname = WS.Range("A4").Value
    Range("B2").Value = y
    Range("C2").Value = 3                        'expected value of B2
    Range("D2").Value = WS.Range("A4").Value     ' expected value is Ontario Airport

End Sub
```

When I run this code, here is the output:

```
B1: 0   C1: 2  D1: Long Beach Airport
B2: 0   C2: 3  D2: Ontario Airport
MsgBox: Something's Wrong
```

I tried moving the Case statement to be after the code and it still doesn't work.  I'm not sure why the Case doesn't seem to be assigning a value to the variable y and returning that.

Comment: Should you have the select case in a function which takes airport name as input. Then call it twice?

Comment: Apparently not.  I thought that Case worked like a function that was able to be referenced multiple times.

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://pastebin.com/PqH9W3ip

Answer (score 2):

Found out that it wasn't returning expected value because the case needs to implemented right after it was called.  Thought it worked like a function that would test whichever value I gave it at any time.

To clarify, I moved the Case to be a function that will return the value whenever it's called.

```
Option Explicit   
Option Compare Text

Sub airport()
    Dim airport As String
    airport = AirportNum(WS.Range("A2").Value) 
    Range("B1").Value = airport
    Range("C1").Value = 2                        'expected value of B1
    Range("D1").Value = WS.Range("A2").Value     'expected value is Long Beach Airport
    airport = AirportNum(WS.Range("A4").Value)
    Range("B2").Value = y
    Range("C2").Value = 3                        'expected value of B2
    Range("D2").Value = WS.Range("A4").Value     ' expected value is Ontario Airport

End Sub

Function AirportNum (AirportName As String) As Long
Select Case True
   Case AirportName Like "Los Ang*" : AirportNum = 1
   Case AirportName Like "Long*" : AirportNum = 2
   Case AirportName Like "Ont*" : AirportNum = 3
   Case AirportName Like "Palm*" : AirportNum = 4
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is the correct approach with `AirportNum()` function since now you have re-usable code for future use.